# How to input a string as argv in python?

Tags: python

I'm debugging a python program named test.py as this:

```
#!/bin/env python
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
```

when I enter this command, result is confuse:

```
[root@yf-mos-test-net09 ~]# python test.py "{"execute": "guest-execute", "session": "4768", "arguments": {"commands": [{"command": "/bin/sh", "arguments": ["sh", "-c", "ping -c 1 8.8.8.8"]}]}}"
```

result is:

```
{execute: guest-execute, session: 4768, arguments: {commands: [{command: /bin/sh, arguments: [sh, -c, ping
```

what I expect should be:

```
{"execute": "guest-execute", "session": "4768", "arguments": {"commands": [{"command": "/bin/sh", "arguments": ["sh", "-c", "ping -c 1 8.8.8.8"]}]}}
```

How to fix this? Is there something wrong in my param or something wrong in my program? Thank you~

Answer (score 3):

It's actually your understanding of the shell that is failing you here :)

What you should do is use different quotes or escape them.

Try this for instance (notice the single quote around the json):

```
[root@yf-mos-test-net09 ~]# python test.py '{"execute": "guest-execute", "session": "4768", "arguments": {"commands": [{"command": "/bin/sh", "arguments": ["sh", "-c", "ping -c 1 8.8.8.8"]}]}}'
```

But it will probably depend on what shell you are using.